# Get rows whose value isn't found on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do the following.
I have [Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3OnK.png) and [Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2rqn.png).

On a third sheet I need to get the rows in sheet 1 where the INSTRUMENT of sheet 1 aren't found in the FIM of sheet 2  (e.g. since none of the INSTRUMENTS of sheet 1 are in the FIM of sheet 2, sheet 3 would contain the rows of sheet 1).
How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Since none of the INSTRUMENTS of sheet 1 are in the FIM of sheet 2, in that case all records from Sheet2 will e  in Sheet 1 ,,  but Headers of  both sheets are not matching, so the question is where to copy data!! Please [edit] your post and  be clear and loud about your need.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup functions like `VLOOKUP()` can be used to either find the lookup value and therefore return some result, or not find it and therefore return an #ERROR!. Obviously, this is usually used in a "positive" sense, looking FOR some result, but one can also use it in a "negative" sense, looking NOT for some result, but rather for the #ERROR!.

One can also then test for the existence of an #ERROR! with the `ISERROR()` function. Sometimes `IFERROR()` can be used, but many situations do not lend themselves to `IFERROR()`'s mechanism and this is one of them. `ISERROR()` will be used here as a more sophisticated `NOT()`. Then, if the INSTRUMENT is not found, the `IF()` test will succeed since it is looking for such a failure. The TRUE result in that case is the value of the lookup cell. If the test fails (INSTRUMENT exists there), "" is returned.

The following formula does this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A9,$F$2:$F$5,1,FALSE)),A2:A9,"")
```

If you have `SPILL` functionality, just the first cell needs the formula. If not, paste it in the first cell and use {CSE} to do the older method for making an array.

Notice that the formula will have results spotted throughout the output range. To group them, you need to sort them with the empty ones ending up at the bottom of the list so they don't interfere with either the easy use of the list, or simply its appearance, whichever might matter more to you.

However, pretty much anything you use for those that exist, like the "" in the formula above, of even a much higher character, like `UNICODE(160)` which owuld be a blank space, will still sort to the start of the list. You could approach that many ways, including copying, then pasting as values, then sorting, but to do it with a formula so you don't need to interact, you can try something like the following:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SORT(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A9,$F$2:$F$5,1,FALSE)),A2:A9,"ZZZZZZZZZZ")),"ZZZZZZZZZZ","")
```

You use a character string that should always sort to the end of your list. "ZZZZZZZZZZ" is used in this formula. Then you `SORT()` to force all those to the end and the ones you want to see first at the top. Then you `SUBSTITUTE()` for that string with a blank, like "", and all those "go away"... Not really of course, but in appearance.

(Obviously, you need to use real references in the formula you choose or adapt.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Reall like this solution. Sadly cant use SORT(), because the version of excel being used. Any work around?